# Blazor WASM: change default strategy for passing arrays in query strings

Tags: blazor-webassembly, querystringparameter

By default, it seems like the most accepted convention for passing arrays as querystring parameters is to use uri in the form:

```
https://.../something?arr=1&arr=2&arr=3
```

ASP.NET web api can also handle querystring parameters arrays passeds like this:

```
https://.../something?arr[0]=1&arr[1]=2&arr[2]=3
```

Anyway for making Blazor use and generate querystring parameters array with this last syntax?

Thanks